# How to query Ravendb document size

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a scenario in which I need to find the largest documents in my Ravendb database.

When I select any given document in Ravendb Studio, the size is displayed in the Properties section as circled in red in this screen shot:

[image: document properties]

Is there a query I can run that will order documents by this Size property so that I can identity the largest documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe write a method that calculates your object size, probably using reflection.
Then, create a [static Map Index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-map-index) with a field '*size*',
and set it with your method that you will provide in the '**additional sources**' in the index 
See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-map-index#additional-sources
And then you could query this index and order-by the '*size*' field

**fyi** - you can get a specific document size using the following endpoint:

```
{yourServerUrl}/databases/{yourDatabaseName}/docs/size?id={yourDocumentId}
```

Learn about ravenDB rest api in: 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/rest-api/rest-api-intro

Answer (score 1):

Index (Map) definition:

```
from doc in docs
select new {
    doc.BlittableJson.Size
}
```